# Level Sets in $R^2$ (Answer Verification)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose that $A\subset R^k$ is nonempty and suppose that we have a function $d:R^k\to R$ such that $$d(x)=\inf \{||x-a||:a\in A\}, x\in R^k$$

If $X=[-1,1]\times [-1,1]\subset R^2$ and $A=\{(1,0),(-1,0)\}\subset R^2$, then what are the level sets $\{x\in R^ : d(x)=y\}$ when $y=0,1,2$

**My thoughts:**
I was thinking that when $y=0$, the level set is a line from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$, when $y=1$, the level set is a line from $(2,0)$ to $(-2,0)$, and when $y=2$, the level set is a line from $(3,0)$ to $(-3,0)$. Can someone confirm this for me?

Comment: Just to be sure, $A$ is the finite set only containing the two points $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$?

Comment: @Demophilus Yes

Comment: Could you maybe add your reasoning to your question, because your answers are far from correct. That would make it easier to help you. Note for example that the line from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$ is contained in the line from $(2,0)$ to $(-2,0)$ which is again contained in the line from $(3,0)$ to $(-3,0)$. So according to you the point $x = (0,0)$ would be in all three level sets, in other words $d(x) = 0$, $d(x)=1$ and $d(x)=2$ would all be true. It goes without saying that this can't be correct.

Comment: Hint: What would the level sets be if $A$ contained only one point instead of two?

Comment: @Demophilus Would it just be the two points then, instead of the entire line?

Comment: @ConnorHarris It would just be that point

Comment: @user23899 Correct.

Comment: @Demophilus So for e.g. y=2 it would just be the points (3,0) and (-3,0)?

Comment: @user23899 No, it will be a lot more points than that. Try to think about what happens when $A$ is just one point and then try to generalise that.

Comment: @Demophilus Is this correct: For y=0, it would just be the points (1,0) and (-1,0). For y=1, it would be a line from (2,0) to (1,0) and from (-2,0) to (-1,0) and for y=2, it would be a line from (3,0) to (2,0) and from (-3,0) to (-2,0)

Comment: @user23899 No, again what would be the level set for $y=1$ if $A=\{(0,0)\}$?

Comment: @Demophilus It would just be that point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67666/discussion-between-demophilus-and-user23899).